Homology + Chinese Remainder Theorem =?
Let $M_i, i=1..n$ be a finite collection of pair-wise coprime moduli.  The Chinese remainder theorem says that $\Bbb{Z}/M \approx \prod_i \Bbb{Z}/M_i$.  Without going into Bezout / Euclidean algorithm, we can say that if $X = a_i \mod M_i$, then, the unique solution modulo $M$ that these assignments correspond to is precisely:
$$
X = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{M}{M_i}\right)^{\varphi(M_i)} a_i \mod M
$$
The proof is simply: take $X$ modulo each $M_i$ and apply Fermat's Little Theorem.  The crazy-looking exponential factor will either be $0$ or $1$ modulo $M_i$.
Let $B_i = \left(\frac{M}{M_i}\right)^{\varphi(M_i)}$.
Thus, if $\sum_i x_i B_i = \sum_i y_i B_i \mod M$, then each $x_i = y_i \mod p_i$.

Define an operator on $\Bbb{Z}/M$ into itself via:
$$
\partial B_i = \sum_{j = 1, \ \\ j \neq i}^{n} (-1)^j\left(\frac{M}{M_i M_j}\right)^{\varphi(M_i M_j)}
$$
and extending $\Bbb{Z}$-linearly.  Then clearly by basic homology theory we have that $Z/M \xrightarrow{\partial} Z/M \xrightarrow{\partial} Z/M \xrightarrow{\partial} \dots$ forms a standard complex.  But all standard complexes are exact.
Question. What is the significance of exactness in this CRT context?
Example. $M = 6$, $M_1 = 2, M_2 = 3$.
Each $X \in \Bbb{Z}/6$ can be written "uniquely" as $X = a_1 3^1 + a_2 2^2$.  Then $\partial X =a_1 -a_2 \mod 6$.  But $\partial((a_1 - a_2) \cdot 1) = \partial ((a_1 - a_2)(3 + 2^2)) = (a_1- a_2)(1 - 1) = 0 \mod 6$.

Note, not sure if re-indexing of the $M_i$ is required before applying $\partial$ to a term.
